# How to do axios.get when the url is password protected in react native?

Tags: react-native, base64, axios

I am trying to do `axios.get`. When I put the url on browser and hit enter browser assk me username and password. But I don't know how to set the password and username in axios header in a get method. The Swagger UI is http://api.myslambook.in/swagger/#

This is my code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import base64 from 'react-native-base64'

export function FriendRequests ( ) {

    state = {
        serverData: [],
    };

    const tok = 'myusername:mypassword';
    const hash = base64.encode(tok);
    const Basic = 'Basic ' + hash;

    axios.get('http://api.myslambook.in/users', {headers : { 'Authorization' : Basic }})
    .then(res => {
        const serverData = res.data;
        this.setState({ serverData });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

I am getting this error in console:

```
Request failed with status code 401.
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For basic authentication the `auth` object can be used:

```
axios.get('http://api.myslambook.in/users', {
    auth: {
        username: 'janedoe',
        password: 's00pers3cret'
    }
}).then(res => {
    const serverData = res.data;
    this.setState({serverData});
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

to fix the `Can't find variable: btoa` error:

```
npm i -S base-64
```

and add the following to `index.js`:

```
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'

if (!global.btoa) {
    global.btoa = encode;
}

if (!global.atob) {
    global.atob = decode;
}
```

Checkout the docs: https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

Comment: Hi, By trying your answer, I got this in console: Can't find variable: btoa